# Use inline styles instead of classes for images in froala

Tags: froala

Is there an easy way to force Froala to use inline styles instead of classes to align images?

In other words, when froala align an image the html output becomes

```
<img src="..." class="fr-dii fr-fil">
```

But I need it to be

```
<img src="..." style="float: left;">
```

Answer (score 0):

well. I know is late to answer but I faced the same problem. I followed steps in the [example](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/examples/image-styles) from the official page and nothing.

The only one solution for my problem was create a button(`<div class="mybutton">`), when I pressed it, the content in editor(`<div id="edit">`) was copied into a `<div class="result">` and and make something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".mybutton").click(function(){
      var text = $('#edit').froalaEditor('html.get');
      // copying to div
      $('#result').html( text );

      //here I add a bootstrap class to every img tag in div 
      $('#result').find("img").addClass('img-responsive');
    });
  });
```

As you can see, you can create your class and add your style and custom every img tag

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the image.js code, you can set a few options to achieve this:

`imageDefaultDisplay` can be set to 'block' or 'inline'

https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#imageDefaultDisplay

Then, set the `useClasses` option to `false`. (This will prevent classes from being used *everywhere*, so be careful)

https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#useClasses

Example froala init code:

```
$("#wysiwyg").froalaEditor({
    useClasses: false,
    imageDefaultDisplay: 'block'
});
```

Then, when you float an image to the right, it will render like this:

**(`useClasses: false` and `imageDefaultDisplay: 'block'`):**

`<img src="http://www.fakewebsite.com/images/image.jpg" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px; max-width: calc(100% - 5px); text-align: right; float: right;">`

or

**(`useClasses: false` and `imageDefaultDisplay: 'inline'`):**

`<img src="http://www.fakewebsite.com/images/image.jpg" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px; max-width: calc(100% - 5px); text-align: right; float: right;">`